# if else statement to check for date entered

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am having trouble getting past the else statement when determining if a date as been chosen.

My app is for displaying a list of classes, along with times of next class. Some classes don't have times assigned at all, but I don't want to keep the field empty so I wrote a a simple if else statement to check if date on class is found, display dates else display a button that links to contact page.

The if works as expected and displays times, but somehow doesn't make it past to render the button on the classes with no dates.

Here is my template code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <strong>Upcoming Training Dates</strong><br />
    {% for dates in classes.training_date.all %}
      {% if dates.course_date != "" %}
        <span class="course-dates">{{ dates.course_date|date:"M d"|upper }}</span>
       {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="padding: 5px 10px!important"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact Us for Training Times</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Updated Question**

Model

```
class TrainingSchedule(models.Model):
    COURSES = (
        ('Food Handlers', 'Food Handlers'),
        ('RABS', 'RABS'),
        ('Managers-Class', 'Managers-Class'),
        ('Managers-Test', 'Managers-Test'),
    )
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=COURSES, default=None, blank=True, verbose_name='Course Title')
    course_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Course Date", blank=True, default=None)
    ...

class TrainingClasses(models.Model):
    ...
    training_date = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingSchedule, default=None, blank=True)
    ...
```

View

```
def training_classes(request):
    classes = TrainingClasses.objects.all().order_by('title')
    training_dates = TrainingSchedule.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'foodapp/training_classes.html', {
        'classes': classes,
        'training_dates': training_dates,
        'key': settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like
      {% if dates.course_date %}

Comment: That displays the dates but not the button after the `else`

Comment: I'm not sure which button but there is one inside of the else.

Comment: Yes, the button inside the else should display if no date is entered for the class.

Comment: Hmm, that should work unless some of your dates accepts an empty string. What is the field type for course_date?

Answer (score 0):

Without further context I'd imagine that the `course_date` is a date, and they never equal strings which is why you always get the date

```
{% if dates.course_date %}
```

Should be enough to resolve the issue

Comment: That will have the opposite effect and display the else line when a course date is available.

Comment: This is exactly what it did.

Comment: @StudioRooster - You should update your question to include more details about what `course_date` is

Comment: @StudioRooster - You've missed out the `TrainingSchedule` which would contain the info about what a `course_date` is

Comment: @StudioRooster - Your model is exactly what I thought it would be and this should work... you could try doing it explicitly `if dates.course_date is not None` but that is the same as this essentially, as a debugging step you can try to print out `{{dates.course_date}}` above your if check

Comment: Tried that but it gives me an "Operator expected" error immediately after the `dates.course_date'

Comment: @StudioRooster - Could you update your question with exactly what it was you tried? I